# MSSQL CDC for views and stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view, change-data-capture

is it possible to enable CDC for Views or Stored procedures?

BR,
Val

Comment: No, Change data capture (CDC) records insert, update, and delete activity that applies to a SQL Server table. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: if you are looking to do versioning of your sql objects you can check my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210450/10267)